# Regex pattern tantrums

Tags: regex

I am trying to find the best regular expression pattern to extract a sub string from a string.

The string is of the type,

> 0816606366.Univ.of.Minnesota.Pr.Minnesota.Messenia.Expedition.Reconstructing.a.Bronze.Age.Regional.Environment.Jun.1972.pdf

I would like to create a regex that would give me everything after the first period. So in this case, the required sub string would be,

> Univ.of.Minnesota.Pr.Minnesota.Messenia.Expedition.Reconstructing.a.Bronze.Age.Regional.Environment.Jun.1972.pdf

I tried

- `\w+`
- `\w*`
- `[\w]*`

and everything else in between but Im just not able to get the result I want. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you

edit: My apologies. I forgot to mention the programming language I was using. I am using Python and the re module that it comes with.

Comment: Have you considered using a simple `Substring`, or equivalent in your language? In C#, you'd use something like `string sub = s.Substring(s.IndexOf('.')+1);`.

Comment: This is a _very_ basic use of regex. @AJ - if you're going to use regex you should really learn some of the basics first (a regex is like a loaded weapon and should be treated with great care or you will shoot yourself in the foot!) Check out the free online tutorials at [regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: I wanted to use regex since I am trying to learn it and I figured that for what I wanted to do it was more efficient.

Comment: Regexes will be *less* efficient than substring, but it's not likely to matter unless you're doing thousands or millions of these matches per second. For learning, sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\d+\.(.+)
```

and replacement is

```
$1
```

Documentation is:

- `\d` match a digit
- `\d+` match more than one digit
- `\d+\.` followed by a "."
- `\d+\..+` followed by anything
- `\d+\.(.+)` capture the "anything" chunk

i tested it at [RegEx Planet](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html):

Regular Expression: `\d+\.(.+)`
Replacement: `$1`
Test String#1: `0816606366.Univ.of.Minnesota.Pr.Minnesota.Messenia.Expedition.Reconstructing.a.Bronze.Age.Regional.Environment.Jun.1972.pdf`

Result: `Univ.of.Minnesota.Pr.Minnesota.Messenia.Expedition.Reconstructing.a.Bronze.Age.Regional.Environment.Jun.1972.pdf`

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly. Although I modified it a little bit. I used '\w+\.(.+)' to catch any non-numeric characters that may appear before the first period as well.

Answer (score 4):

Simple regex to separate the first part from the rest:

```
/^.+?\.(.+)$/
```

Then just grab the content of capturing group 1.

To explain it:

`^` and `$` match the start end end the string.

`.+?` is a non-greedy match for any number of any character (non-greedy (denoted by the question mark) because otherwise it would match the whole string; this way it stops at the dot to allow the rest of the expression to match)

`\.` is a dot character, which is our delimiter.

`(.+)` another any number of any characters match; this time it's greedy because we don't mind; there's nothing after it anyway. Wrapped in brackets to make it into a capturing group, so we can extract it from the regex engine.

You haven't specified the language you're working in, but a generic bit of code could look something like this:

```
var output = input.replace(/^.+?\.(.+)$/,"$1");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can be simplified to just: `/\.(.*)/`

Comment: Does the regex depend on the language we use? I always thought the syntax of regex patterns was a language unto itself. And therefore, standardized across different programming languages. Did I assume wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was able to use your explanation to shorten it a bit by modifying the regex in your answer. Result = '.+?\.(.+)'

Comment: @AJ - regex is generally fairly similar between languages, but there are indeed some variations in syntax and features (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for some good info on this). It shouldn't make any difference to this expression, but it obviously does make a difference in the code you'd need to use to extract the capturing group results.

Answer (score 2):

```
^[^\.]+\.(.+)$
```

- ^ start ^
- [^.]+ all not . chars
- . the first .
- (.*) the rest
- $ the end

Comment: I don't think the dot needs to be escaped when it's inside a `[]` character class group.

Comment: ...hmmm... I don't know. I would have said not, but I guess it depends how  you are at reading regex. :-)

Comment: @Jens Struwe I don't think so, but nice explanation ;-) I would generally write this regex as `^[^.]+[.](.+)$`

Comment: Ok ... ridgerunner has posted the shortest version: `\.(.*)`. It starts with the first dot and goes greedy to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You should certainly read the manual first before posting a question this specific. If you have a Unix-like environment with the Perl documentation installed, this should be your first stop:

```
perldoc perlre
```

Alternatively, you can [read the documentation online](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

perl -e '"ab.cd.ef.gh" =~ m/[^.]+.(.+)/; print $1'

```
[.]   # Use the square bracket to match a given set of characters. 
[^.]  # Use the caret symbol to invert the matching set. 
[^.]+ # The plus symbol matches one or more of the previous symbol. 
\.    # The escaping backslash and period matches a literal period character
()    # Use parenthesis to capture a submatch
(.+)  # Use the period to match any one character and the plus
```

Here's a great tool for building regular expressions:

```
http://txt2re.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this as you can see above. The way I prefer is:

```
^[^.]*\.(.*)$
```

- **^** means start of sentence.
- **[^.]*** is zero or more characters that are not "."
- **.** is the period. You need to add the "\" before it (. means any character otherwise)
- **(.*)** is zero or more characters. Parenthesis means this is what we want to extract.
- **$** is end of line

You can test all sorts of methods out on the fly here:

> http://www.pythonregex.com/